# App crashes because of attempt to invoke virtual method ' ' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a custom dialog box appear when I click on an image in recyclerview. However, though there are no apparent errors in code when compiling, my app keeps crashing when I click onto the menu-item to enter the page. The error in logcat says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.myndapplication.adapter.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:61)
        at com.example.android.myndapplication.adapter.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:25)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:572)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3686)
```

Below I have inserted the code I have on the matter currently:

**  UserAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.myndapplication.R;
import com.example.android.myndapplication.model.User;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> userList;
    Dialog myDialog;




    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> userList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.userList = userList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder ViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        // Dialog ini
        myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_profile);
        CircleImageView iv_profile = (CircleImageView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_image);
        TextView tv_username = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_username);
        TextView tv_date = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_date);
        ImageView iv_content = (ImageView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_content_image);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final User user = userList.get(position);
        holder.iv_profile.setImageResource(user.getProfileImage());
        holder.userName.setText(user.getUserName());
        holder.userDate.setText(user.getUserDate());
        holder.image_content.setImageResource(user.getImage());
        holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test Click"+userList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CardView item;
        private CircleImageView iv_profile;
        private TextView userName;
        private TextView userDate;
        private ImageView image_content;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textView;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_bookmarks);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_bookmarks);
            item = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_item);
            iv_profile = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_image);
            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_username);
            userDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_date);
            image_content = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_content_image);

            //test
            //itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        }
    }

}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {

    private int image;
    private String Title;
    private String UserName;
    private int profileImage;
    private String userDate;


    public String getUserDate() {
        return userDate;
    }

    public void setUserDate(String userDate) {
        this.userDate = userDate;
    }

    public User(int image, String Title, String userName, int profileImage, String userDate) {
        this.image = image;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
        this.userDate = userDate;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public int getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(int profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setUserName(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }
}
```

**dialog_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_profile_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dialog_profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_profile_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="date"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dialog_profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_profile_username" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_content_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have checked through my id's, and tried to make sure that I have setContentView, as I have seen being the issue for problems similar to mine. However, nothing seems to work, and I can't really spot the mistake. I hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are not getting compile-time error is that you have those ids valid in `dialog_profile.xml` layout but the recycler item layout is different which is `recycler_list_item` see your `onCreateViewHolder`.

That is the reason for runtime NullPointerException on the `CircleImageView` because that is not part of your  `recycler_list_item` which is currently inflated when your adapter is been created.

**Note:** Always make sure the view you are using in viewholder is in the layout adapter is inflating, because you will not get compile-time error in case you are doing it wrong but at runtime, it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but, in the "OnBindViewHolder", can you try to access "iv_profile" from the itemView of the view holder?

I mean like this:

```
holder.itemView.iv_profile.setImageResource(user.getProfileImage());
```

instead of this:

```
holder.iv_profile.setImageResource(user.getProfileImage());
```

My assumption is that your reference is in the View and not bound to the holder itself.

Comment: I have a doubt. Can you try to declare "CircleImageView iv_profile" outside of the "OnCreateViewHolder" block?